# dplyr left join displays more join variables than specified

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping, left-join

Ok so here's my problem. I'm trying to scrape a ton of data off of websites. My code looks like this:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rlist)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

team_performance <- read.csv("C:/Users/Will/Documents/team_performance.csv")
stats_names <- read.csv("C:/Users/Will/Documents/stats_names.csv")
date_vals <- read.csv("C:/Users/Will/Documents/date_vals.csv")
teams_list <- read.csv("C:/Users/Will/Documents/teams_list.csv")

date_vals <- date_vals[[1]]
stats_names <- stats_names[[1]]
team_stats <- NULL

for(i in c(0:10)){
  burner <- teams_list
  burner$Year <- (2007 + i)
  team_stats <- rbind(team_stats, burner)
}

names(team_stats)[[1]] <- "Team"



percent_complete <- 0

for(x in date_vals){
  for(i in stats_names){
    mpg_link <- getURL(paste0("https://www.teamrankings.com/ncaa-    basketball/stat/",gsub(" ","-",i),"?date=",x),.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
    tables <- readHTMLTable(mpg_link)
    tables <- list.clean(tables, fun = is.null, recursive = FALSE)
    n.rows <- unlist(lapply(tables, function(t) dim(t)[1]))
    temp_data <- data.frame(tables)

    temp_data$NULL.Stat <- i

    names(temp_data)[3] <- temp_data$NULL.Stat[1]
    names(temp_data)[2] <- "Team"
    temp_data <- temp_data[,-c(4:8)]
    temp_data$Year <- as.numeric(substr(as.character(x),1,4))

    team_stats <- left_join(team_stats,temp_data[,-c(1,4)], by.x = "Team", by.y = "Year")

    percent_complete <- percent_complete + (100/979)
    print(paste(round(percent_complete,digits=2),"% complete",sep=""))
  }
}
```

After the first year (2017) is done, after the joins are completed, I get a message like this:

```
Joining, by = c("Team", "Year", "Points Per Game")
```

instead of getting a message like this:

```
Joining, by = c("Team", "Year")
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Edit: Ok no longer getting the messages but it still won't switch over the year. Once it starts to scrape 2016, data doesn't show up where the year is 2016.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.

Comment: I don't really know what makes this happen though so I can't reproduce it. That's the issue.

Comment: Is that `dplyr::left_join`? You're supposed to specify the columns to join on by passing a vector of column names (ie: `... by = c('Team', 'Year')`). The `by.x` and `by.y` arguments don't do anything, which it why it automatically joins on all identically named variables and gives you that warning message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `left_join`, the syntax should be

```
left_join(team_stats,temp_data[,-c(1,4)], by=c(Team = "Year"))
```

though the column names are not making sense for the join.  It is based on the OP's syntax.

The `by.x` and `by.x` are arguments in `merge` (from `base R`)

---

As a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = rnorm(5))
df2 <- data.frame(A = rep(1:3, each = 2), B = rnorm(6))
```

The OP's method is giving errors in `dplyr_0.7.4`

```
left_join(df2, df1, by.x = 'A', by.y = 'col1')
```

> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common
>   variables

because the arguments don't match

```
left_join(df2, df1, by = c(A= "col1"))
#  A            B       col2
#1 1  0.266021979 -0.5458808
#2 1  0.444585270 -0.5458808
#3 2 -0.466495124  0.5365853
#4 2 -0.848370044  0.5365853
#5 3  0.002311942  0.4196231
#6 3 -1.316908124  0.4196231
```

Comment: Ok wait in that case I think what I would actually want is

`left_join(team_stats,temp_data[,-c(1,4)], by=c("Team" = "Team", "Year" = "Year"))`

Is this correct?

Comment: @wscheib  If the column names are the same in both, then you don't ned the `=` i.e. `left_join(team_stats, temp_data[,-c(1,4)], by= c("Team", "Year"))`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm still having an issue though. See the edit. Any ideas for why this might be the case?

Comment: It's almost like joining by the Year isn't doing anything.

Comment: @wscheib  Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to go through.  I would suggest to check this line by line, i.e. for a single set of datasets instead of the loop to figure out the problem

Comment: Ok wait I figured out what it's doing. When it switches years, the join changes the name of the first variable column to something like Points Per Game.x and adds a new column called Points Per Game.y with the new data. Is there a way to just have it add the data to the existing column? Does that make any sense?

Comment: @wscheib  Perhaps you need `semi_join` i.e. `semi_join(team_stats, temp_data[,-c(1,4)], by= c("Team", "Year"))`  Or just subset the second dataset with the `by` columns and the column of interest you want to add i.e `left_join(team_stats, temp_data[c("Team", "Year", colofinterst)], by = c("Team", "Year"))`

Comment: Thanks. Trying the `left_join` one right now because `semi_join` gave me an error

Comment: Ok. The `left_join` one gives the same issue. And the `semi_join` one didn't give me an error, it just didn't do anything. It didn't join anything to anything. I may have messed something up, but it didn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: @wscheib  As I mentioned earlier, just take the two datasets out of the loop and do the join and see which one gives you the expected output.  It may also be better to check the `str` of both datasets before doing the join

Comment: I figured this one out about a year ago, but thanks